# Alternate to groupBy and collect_list in scala

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

Is there a way to create the below Output Dataframe from the given Input Dataframe without using groupBy and collect_list ?

**Input Dataframe Schema:-**

```
root
 |-- GPS: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- requestid: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- timestamp: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- GPSLatitude: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- GPSLongitude: double (nullable = true)
 |-- requestid: string (nullable = true)
```

**Input DataFrame:-**

| GPS | requestid |
| --- | --- |
| {"requestid":"2b7bfbd4cf7c3124a517a112851ec6015b1ef85b_0","timestamp":1596368673,"GPSLatitude":40.13587319463796,"GPSLongitude":-75.15846220892067} | 2b7bfbd4cf7c3124a517a112851ec6015b1ef85b_0 |
| {"requestid":"2b7bfbd4cf7c3124a517a112851ec6015b1ef85b_0","timestamp":1596368674,"GPSLatitude":40.135924326024096,"GPSLongitude":-75.15865512908896} | 2b7bfbd4cf7c3124a517a112851ec6015b1ef85b_0 |
| {"requestid":"2b7bfbd4cf7c3124a517a112851ec6015b1ef85b_0","timestamp":1596368675,"GPSLatitude":40.13599278802667,"GPSLongitude":-75.15876733291171} | 2b7bfbd4cf7c3124a517a112851ec6015b1ef85b_0 |
| {"requestid":"2b7bfbd4cf7c3124a517a112851ec6015b1ef85b_0","timestamp":1596368676,"GPSLatitude":40.136083261014484,"GPSLongitude":-75.15885143441842} | 2b7bfbd4cf7c3124a517a112851ec6015b1ef85b_0 |
| {"requestid":"2b7bfbd4cf7c3124a517a112851ec6015b1ef85b_0","timestamp":1596368677,"GPSLatitude":40.13616687156273,"GPSLongitude":-75.1589827147081} | 2b7bfbd4cf7c3124a517a112851ec6015b1ef85b_0 |
| {"requestid":"2b7bfbd4cf7c3124a517a112851ec6015b1ef85b_1","timestamp":1596368833,"GPSLatitude":40.14496631033691,"GPSLongitude":-75.17361394861283} | 2b7bfbd4cf7c3124a517a112851ec6015b1ef85b_1 |
| {"requestid":"2b7bfbd4cf7c3124a517a112851ec6015b1ef85b_1","timestamp":1596368834,"GPSLatitude":40.14509290798243,"GPSLongitude":-75.17385201087406} | 2b7bfbd4cf7c3124a517a112851ec6015b1ef85b_1 |
| {"requestid":"2b7bfbd4cf7c3124a517a112851ec6015b1ef85b_1","timestamp":1596368835,"GPSLatitude":40.145218343731,"GPSLongitude":-75.17407707132585} | 2b7bfbd4cf7c3124a517a112851ec6015b1ef85b_1 |
| {"requestid":"2b7bfbd4cf7c3124a517a112851ec6015b1ef85b_1","timestamp":1596368836,"GPSLatitude":40.145350564938425,"GPSLongitude":-75.17430271187274} | 2b7bfbd4cf7c3124a517a112851ec6015b1ef85b_1 |
| {"requestid":"2b7bfbd4cf7c3124a517a112851ec6015b1ef85b_1","timestamp":1596368837,"GPSLatitude":40.14548270568285,"GPSLongitude":-75.17452650958782} | 2b7bfbd4cf7c3124a517a112851ec6015b1ef85b_1 |
| {"requestid":"2b7bfbd4cf7c3124a517a112851ec6015b1ef85b_2","timestamp":1596368838,"GPSLatitude":40.14560747391316,"GPSLongitude":-75.17474553105055} | 2b7bfbd4cf7c3124a517a112851ec6015b1ef85b_2 |
| {"requestid":"2b7bfbd4cf7c3124a517a112851ec6015b1ef85b_2","timestamp":1596368839,"GPSLatitude":40.14560753483339,"GPSLongitude":-75.17474563799348} | 2b7bfbd4cf7c3124a517a112851ec6015b1ef85b_2 |

**Output DataFrame:-**

| requestid | GPS |
| --- | --- |
| 2b7bfbd4cf7c3124a517a112851ec6015b1ef85b_0 | [{"requestid":"2b7bfbd4cf7c3124a517a112851ec6015b1ef85b_0","timestamp":1596368673,"GPSLatitude":40.13587319463796,"GPSLongitude":-75.15846220892067},{"requestid":"2b7bfbd4cf7c3124a517a112851ec6015b1ef85b_0","timestamp":1596368674,"GPSLatitude":40.135924326024096,"GPSLongitude":-75.15865512908896},{"requestid":"2b7bfbd4cf7c3124a517a112851ec6015b1ef85b_0","timestamp":1596368675,"GPSLatitude":40.13599278802667,"GPSLongitude":-75.15876733291171},{"requestid":"2b7bfbd4cf7c3124a517a112851ec6015b1ef85b_0","timestamp":1596368676,"GPSLatitude":40.136083261014484,"GPSLongitude":-75.15885143441842},{"requestid":"2b7bfbd4cf7c3124a517a112851ec6015b1ef85b_0","timestamp":1596368677,"GPSLatitude":40.13616687156273,"GPSLongitude":-75.1589827147081}] |
| 2b7bfbd4cf7c3124a517a112851ec6015b1ef85b_1 | [{"requestid":"2b7bfbd4cf7c3124a517a112851ec6015b1ef85b_1","timestamp":1596368833,"GPSLatitude":40.14496631033691,"GPSLongitude":-75.17361394861283},{"requestid":"2b7bfbd4cf7c3124a517a112851ec6015b1ef85b_1","timestamp":1596368834,"GPSLatitude":40.14509290798243,"GPSLongitude":-75.17385201087406},{"requestid":"2b7bfbd4cf7c3124a517a112851ec6015b1ef85b_1","timestamp":1596368835,"GPSLatitude":40.145218343731,"GPSLongitude":-75.17407707132585},{"requestid":"2b7bfbd4cf7c3124a517a112851ec6015b1ef85b_1","timestamp":1596368836,"GPSLatitude":40.145350564938425,"GPSLongitude":-75.17430271187274},{"requestid":"2b7bfbd4cf7c3124a517a112851ec6015b1ef85b_1","timestamp":1596368837,"GPSLatitude":40.14548270568285,"GPSLongitude":-75.17452650958782}] |
| 2b7bfbd4cf7c3124a517a112851ec6015b1ef85b_2 | [{"requestid":"2b7bfbd4cf7c3124a517a112851ec6015b1ef85b_2","timestamp":1596368838,"GPSLatitude":40.14560747391316,"GPSLongitude":-75.17474553105055},{"requestid":"2b7bfbd4cf7c3124a517a112851ec6015b1ef85b_2","timestamp":1596368839,"GPSLatitude":40.14560753483339,"GPSLongitude":-75.17474563799348}] |

**Output Dataframe schema:-**

```
root
 |-- requestid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- GPS: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- requestid: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- timestamp: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- GPSLatitude: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- GPSLongitude: double (nullable = true)
```

Version : (spark 2.45 and scala 2.11)

Comment: why do you want to avoid `collect_list` when it is the most straightforward way to do it?

Comment: @mck In the above example I just have 12 records grouped in batches of 5 based on 'requestid'. What if I have 500 million records that needs to be grouped in batches of 5000. In this scenario I'm afraid collect_list will crash the driver (112GB, 16 cores). Am I wrong or can I still use collect_list in this case as well?

Comment: I guess a list of 5000 items might not crash a driver with 112GB. Have you tried it and crashed the driver?

Comment: These operations should be performed in parallel on the workers. I don't expect the driver to be heavily involved.

Comment: I have tried it with 70 million records grouped in batches of 5000 and it hasn't crashed the driver. However the collect_list returns a dataframe with number of partitions as 1 (dataframe.rdd.getNumPartitions). Each row in my dataframe is the body of an http request that needs to be posted to an external service. To make multiple api calls at once I need to repartition the dataframe dataframe.repartition(65).foreachPartition(_.foreach(x => makeHttpCall(x))) 
Since 'repartition' is an expensive operation I was checking ways to optimize the application so that I could do a coalesce instead.

Comment: hmm, I assume you did collect_list through a groupBy. There shouldn't be only 1 partition after a group by... how many partitions were there before group by?

Comment: After the 'explode' I have 3700 partitions. But to do the groupBy I am first assigning an index to each of the 70 million records based on its row number, dividing the row_number by 5000 to get the quotient and then grouping by the quotient
 explodeDF.withColumn("id",  row_number().over(Window.orderBy(monotonically_increasing_id()))).withColumn("requestid", floor($"id" / 5000).groupBy("requestid").agg(collect_list($"GPS"))
I believe the part that does the indexing brings all the records to 1 partition since it has to auto increment over each record.

Comment: This is not an efficient way of batching. Could you try `repartition(5000)`? And use [spark_partition_id](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.spark_partition_id). No need for row_number/monotonically_increasing_id

Comment: So the 70 million exploded records need to be batched in groups of 5000 which is a total of 14000 batches. Should I try explodeDF.repartition(14000).select("GPS", spark_partition_id().alias("id")).groupBy("id").collect_list("GPS") ?

Comment: oh yes that's right. You can give it a try

Comment: After the shuffle it outputs the default 200 partitions which is great. But when I run the post api call I get a "connection reset" error. I've been seeing this error message earlier as well when i repartition with anything greater than 65. I will need to go figure this out. Thanks for your recommendations

Comment: You can explicitly coalesce to a smaller number of partitions after groupby and collect_list, if that's helpful

Comment: Yes thats what I did and got the connection error. Im checking if this is a problem on the external service to which i post the http request
val groupDF = explodeDF.repartition(14001)
.withColumn("id", spark_partition_id())
.select(col("id"), col("GPS"))
.groupBy("id").agg(collect_list(col("GPS")).as("GPS"))
.select($"GPS")

After this I do the coalesce and execute the post method
groupDF.coalesce(50).foreachPartition(_.foreach(x => makeHttpCall(x.getString(0))))